# thread dump of Java using Kill -3

Tags: thread

I used to take thread dumps using:

```
kill -3 `pidof java`
```

This will create thread dumps in `catalina.out` ; how to get those output to a file rather than  in `catalina.out`. Usually kill command won't output it to stdout or stderr so we cannot get it from redirecting script to a  log or using exec in at the begining; so is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `jstack $(pidof java) > MYFILE` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Java versions 7 and later have the `jcmd` tool, which is the option recommended by Oracle. `jcmd` aggregates the functionality of multiple diagnostic tools, such as `jstack` and `jmap`.

You can run the following `jcmd` command to get the thread dump of a process with PID 1234 (with output redirected to a file):

```
jcmd 1234 Thread.print > thread-dump.txt
```

More details here: [jcmd Utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html), [jcmd man page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jcmd.html)